# Can I pause postback on an asp.net button and continue after some task is completed?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, button, postback, submit

How can I pause post-back process by javaScript on an asp.net button and continue after some task is completed?

Something like:

```
btnRemove.Attributes["onclick"] = string.Format(@"

var itemId=$.trim($('#{0}').val());                             

// stopPostBack() somehow

// do some stuff with itemId

// continue post-back 

", txtMyTextBox.ClientId);
```

Comment: Depends - what stuff you want to do with the `itemId`?

Comment: Actually my problem is, that select is somehow slow enough to be processed; so that post-back occurs before it selcts the rrelevant textbox. (I deleted the String.Format part btw)

Comment: what select? What textbox? Still not clear, sorry.. :/

Comment: @Shadow Wizard : I have updated the code. I am selecting a textbox and obtain its trimmed value by jquery. And it takes long enough for some reason to be completed before post-back occurs.

Answer (score 2):

All onClick() event code is handled before submission. If the onClick event handler returns false, the event will execute the code, then fail to submit. If it returns true, it will execute the code, then submit.

I don't think you need to "stop" the postback. Just put the code you want before returning true and that will execute before the submission.

Example:

```
btnRemove.Attributes["onclick"] = @"

var itemId=$.trim($('#{0}').val());

alert(itemId);

return true;

";
```

The `alert()` here will be executed before submission.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think with a trick you can do that.

Just return false, to avoid the post back, init a timer to call the next function that make the work, and at the end fire the post back manually.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you just need to return false from a javascript onclick event.

eg:

```
  <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server" 
                                                CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container,&#13;&#10;"RowIndex") %>' 
                                                CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"
                                                onclientclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this Connection?');" 
                                                ToolTip="Delete the connection" />
```